# spring security ldap additional attributes

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I would like to add a few additional ldap attributes (actually just one) to the userdetail object. It seems like the only way to do that is to override the usercontextmapper classes which then involves extending person class and essence class within it. It seems like a little too much work just to add some additional attributes. Before pursuing that route I wanted to make sure that there isnt another easier way to accomplish this.

Basically I have an attribute called "collections" in ldap which I would like to have available on the Principal object within my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to extend the internal classes if you don't want to. The only thing that the [`UserDetailsContextMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ldap-custom-user-details) requires is that the object you return from `mapUserFromContext` implements `UserDetails`.

So you should be able to just read the attributes you want (including "collections") from the LDAP context object (the `DirContextOperations`) and use these to create your instance.